# TCP Socket on Server Side Using Python with select on Windows

Tags: python, windows, sockets, select

By trying to find an optimization to my server on python, I have stumbled on a concept called select. By trying to find any code possible to use, no matter where I looked, Windows compatibility with this subject is hard to find.

Any ideas how to program a TCP server with select on windows? I know about the idea of unblocking the sockets to maintain the compatibility with it. Any suggestions will be welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Using `select()` under Windows is 99% the same as it is under other OS's, with some minor variations.  The minor variations (at least the ones I know about) are:

1. Under Windows, `select()` only works for real network sockets.  In particular, don't bother trying to `select()` on `stdin` under Windows, as it won't work.
2. Under Windows, if you attempt a non-blocking TCP connection and the TCP connection fails asynchronously, you will get a notification of that failure via the third ("exception") fd_set only.  (Under other OS's you will get notified that the failed-to-connect TCP-socket is ready-for-read/write also)
3. Under Windows, `select()` will fail if you don't pass in at least one valid socket to it (so you can't use `select([], [], [], timeoutInSeconds)` as an alternative to `time.sleep()` like you can under some other OS's)

Other than that `select()` for Windows is like `select()` for any other OS.  (If your real question about how to use `select()` in general, you can find information about that using a web search)

Comment: Thanks! I think it;s a fair good answer but yeah. I have heard that you should seperate the input and output via two different threads, is it right?

Comment: If you want to read from `stdin` under Windows, you'll need to do that in a separate thread, because Windows `stdin` support blocking reads only and therefore any thread that tries to read from `stdin` ends up blocked indefinitely (i.e. until some more data comes in to read).  Microsoft makes it as difficult as possible to handle gracefully :(

Comment: All network input and output can be handled in a single thread, though, as long as you use non-blocking sockets and block only inside `select()`.